# Dropdown options linked with php and javascript not showing in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

The options are being pulled from an array but are not showing up on the frontend of the Wordpress site. Please look over the code and tell me if there are any errors as Im still newer to Wordpress development. The input for the dropdown shows but has no functionality

Here is the php file content

```js
function generate_job_sector_options($job_sectors){
    $options = '<option value="">Select a Job Sector</option>';

    foreach($job_sectors as $sector) {
        $options = '<option value="" . $sector["name"] . "">' . $sector['name'] . '</option>';
    }

    return $options;
}
```

```html
<?php 
    get_header();
    pageBanner();
?>

<form id="job-form">
    <label for="job-sector">Job Sector:</label>
    <select id="job-sector" name="job-sector"><?php generate_job_sector_options($job_sectors) ?></select>

    <div id="skills-container"></div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var jobSkills = {
    'IT': ['Programming', 'Networking', 'Database Management'],
    'Marketing': ['Digital Marketing', 'Market Research', 'Advertising']
  };

  document.getElementById('job-sector').addEventListener('change', function(){
    var.selectedSector = this.value;
    var skillsContainer = document.getElementById('skills-container');

    skillsContainer.innerHTML='';

    if(selectedSector) {
        var skills = jobSkills[selectedSector];

        skills.forEach(function(skill){
            var skillElement = document.createElement('p');

            skillsContainer.appendChild(skillElement);
        })
    }
  })
</script>



<?php 
    get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with php, but do you need to `echo` the function result to output the options? Also your `generate_job_sector_options()` function seems to overwrite `$options` for each loop iteration, rather than append to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Inside the function `generate_job_sector_options` you need to **append** to `$options`:

```
foreach($job_sectors as $sector) {
    $options .= '<option value="" . $sector["name"] . "">' . $sector['name'] . '</option>';
}
```

2. Since you're using `return` inside the function, you need to echo the results:

```
    <select id="job-sector" name="job-sector"><?php echo generate_job_sector_options($job_sectors) ?></select>
```

3. You have a `.` instead of a whitespace inside the javascript function:

```
var selectedSector = this.value;
```

You should probably read a little bit about javascript and php debugging. Those things were quite easy to find and fix.